# rebuild a large mysql database on a remote computer

Tags: mysql

Im using mysql version 14.14 on Ubuntu 16.04

I have a large (86Gb) mysql database backed up as a .sql file. I want to rebuild the database on a remote computer but since it takes so long to build (I estimate about 12-24 hours) Im having trouble when the connection fails and stops my job. I tried using nohup but it still says "Terminal close -- query aborted" when I suppose my remote connection is lost. Here is the command I used from the terminal

```
nohup mysql -h 'localhost' rebuiltDB < savedDB.sql &
```

I have some entries in the database but it clearly fail to finish rebuilding; I thought nohup would prevent these types of interruption.

Comment: Are you familiar with `screen` or `tmux`?  Much better solutions than `nohup`, because if you do lose your terminal connection, you can reconnect and reattach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sh -c 'nohup mysql -h localhost rebuiltDB < [absolutePath]/savedDB.sql &'
```

replace [absolutePath] with full path to your savedDB.sql file.